# Can i expose an endpoint from my flink streaming application

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

I would like to expose an end point from my flink streaming application.Which returns some static metadata about the app . What are the possible ways to implement this . Please help

Comment: any help on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sort of metadata would you like to retrieve? Flink exposes a [CLI](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/ops/cli.html) which is enables you to gather data about the running job. Which you are able to use both if you're running it on e.g. Kubernetes or AWS KDA.

You can also [define and expose your own metrics](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/metrics.html) if the CLI doesn't fulfil your use case.